# What is the time complexity of this program to calculate the binomial coefficient and in what ways can I improve it?

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int n=10, k=4;
int ar[10];
void cof(int, int);

int main() { 
    ar[0] = 1;
    cof(n,k);
    return 0;
}

void cof(int n, int k) {
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {
        ar[i] = (i+1)*ar[i-1];
    }
    int l = ar[n-1] / (ar[n-k-1]*ar[k-1]);
    cout << l;
}
```

The code uses the function `cof()` to calculate permutation values till `n` and then uses them for `n` and `k` to calculate the binomial cofficient.

Comment: You only have one loop, bounded by `n` so O(n)

Comment: thanks a lot. isn't this manner called bottom up?

Comment: you can improve it by not using globals. It is confusing to see two different `n` when actually they are the same (same for `k`)

Comment: If the code works and you want to speed it up, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks a lot everyone!!